# How does one set himself up as contractor in Hong Kong?

Tags: paperwork, working, hong-kong

As I understand when one wants to get [working permit in Hong Kong](http://workinginhongkong.com/working-in-hong-kong/hong-kong-visas/#) he must already have job proposal, as well as...

- Higher level educational background: a graduate degree and above would be preferable.
- Relevant experience that is deemed to be in short supply in Hong Kong.
- Reasonable salary level; a guide of US$40,000 per year is considered reasonable.
- How beneficial the individual is to Hong Kong’s economy, trade and industry.
- That a local or resident worker could not fill the position.
- How the expatriate can benefit the local workforce (e.g. training).

However I know that there are quite a few contractors in HK, so how do they manage to do that, or do they have all been in HK for 7 years and have permanent residence?

**How does one set himself up as contractor in Hong Kong?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because frankly, entire books exist on the matter, and it'll eithe produce an ineffectual answer, or multiple partial answers, which is not the goal of Stackexchange. Please see the [help] for more info.